# WinAPI 32 wrapper in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi

This is a piece of code using this wrapper to create a simple window and handle some of it's events in Windows environment.

```
#include "nasui.h"
#include "nasui_ctrls.h"

void ButClick(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_Button *butn);
void BoxPress(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_TextBox *tbox);
void ListSel(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_ListBox *list);
void ScrollScrollScroll(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_ScrollBar *bar);

void WinCreate(NASUI_Window *win);
int WinClose(NASUI_Window *win);
void WinDestroy(NASUI_Window *win);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR cmdargs, int nCmdShow)
{
    NASUI_Window *mywin = NASUI_CreateWindow(hInst, hPrevInst, cmdargs, nCmdShow,
                        "NASUI", 0, 0, 640, 480);
    NASUI_SetOnCreateHandler(mywin, WinCreate);
    NASUI_SetOnCloseHandler(mywin, WinClose);
    NASUI_SetOnDestroyHandler(mywin, WinDestroy);

    NASUI_Run(mywin);
}

void ListSel(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_ListBox *list)
{
    char *tofr = NASUI_GetListBoxSelectedItem(list);
    printf("selected %s\n", tofr);
    free(tofr);
}
void ScrollScrollScroll(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_ScrollBar *bar)
{
    printf("scroll scroll scroll\n");
}

void WinCreate(NASUI_Window *win)
{
    printf("onCreate()\n"); 
    NASUI_Button *butex = NASUI_CreateButton(5, 5, 100, 25, "a button");
    NASUI_AddControl(win, (NASUI_Control*)butex);

    NASUI_TextBox *tbex = NASUI_CreateTextBox(5, 30, 100, 25, "enter something");
    NASUI_AddControl(win, (NASUI_Control*)tbex);

    NASUI_ListBox *lst = NASUI_CreateListBox(5, 55, 200, 200);
    NASUI_SetOnListBoxSelectHandler(lst, ListSel);
    NASUI_AddControl(win, (NASUI_Control*)lst);
    NASUI_AddListBoxItem(lst, "THIS");
    NASUI_AddListBoxItem(lst, "USEFUL");
    NASUI_AddListBoxItem(lst, "ANSI");
    NASUI_AddListBoxItem(lst, "с неколькими кодировками");

    NASUI_ScrollBar *scbar = NASUI_CreateScrollBar(205, 55, 25, 200, NASUI_SCROLLBAR_VERTICAL, 100, 5);
    NASUI_SetOnScrollBarScrollHandler(scbar, ScrollScrollScroll);
    NASUI_AddControl(win, (NASUI_Control*)scbar);
}
int WinClose(NASUI_Window *win)
{   
    printf("onClose()\n"); return 1;
}
void WinDestroy(NASUI_Window *win)
{
    printf("onDestroy()\n");
}
```

Header files:
**nasui.h**

```
#ifndef NASUI_H
#define NASUI_H

#include <windows.h>

typedef struct NASUI_Window NASUI_Window;
typedef struct NASUI_WindowEvents NASUI_WindowEvents;

// WindowEvents possible function pointers
typedef void (*NASUI_onCreate)(NASUI_Window *win);
/*
*   Called on window creation. The window aren't even shown now, either no controls are attached.
*/
typedef int (*NASUI_onClose)(NASUI_Window *win);
/* 
*   Called on user attempt to close the window. Can be cancelled by returning zero.
*/
typedef void (*NASUI_onDestroy)(NASUI_Window *win);
/*
*   Called on the window destruction. Can't be cancelled.
*/



NASUI_Window * NASUI_CreateWindow(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR cmdargs, int nCmdShow,        
                const char *title, int x, int y, int width, int height);
/*
*   First four arguments are fetched from WinMain() and should not be modified.
*   This function prepares Window structure to create a win32 window
*/

void NASUI_SetOnCreateHandler(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_onCreate handler);
void NASUI_SetOnCloseHandler(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_onClose handler);
void NASUI_SetOnDestroyHandler(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_onDestroy handler);

void NASUI_Run(NASUI_Window *win);  
/*
*   This function creates actual window and enters an infinitive loop for fetching and 
*   handling Windows OS messages sent to the window.
*   CAUTION: use only when all preparations are done or moved to another thread!!!
*/  

#endif
```

**nasui_ctrls.h**

```
#ifndef NASUI_CTRLS_H
#define NASUI_CTRLS_H

#include "nasui.h"

typedef struct NASUI_Control NASUI_Control;
void NASUI_AddControl(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_Control *ctrl);
/*
*   Generic polymorhpic structure.
*   Contains generic information about control's coordinates, size, handler and type.
*   It's children are declared below.
*/

//////////////////
// Button   1
typedef struct NASUI_Button NASUI_Button;                           
NASUI_Button * NASUI_CreateButton(int x, int y, int width, int height, const char *text);

typedef void (*NASUI_onButtonClick)(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_Button *button);
void NASUI_SetOnButtonClickHandler(NASUI_Button *button, NASUI_onButtonClick handler);
/*
*   Called on button being clicked. Disabled buttons are ignored.
*/

//////////////////
// TextBox  2
typedef struct NASUI_TextBox NASUI_TextBox;
NASUI_TextBox * NASUI_CreateTextBox(int x, int y, int width, int height, const char *initial_text);

typedef void (*NASUI_onTextBoxKeyPress)(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_TextBox *textbox);
void NASUI_SetOnTextBoxKeyPressHandler(NASUI_TextBox *textbox, NASUI_onTextBoxKeyPress handler);

//////////////////
// ListBox  3
typedef struct NASUI_ListBox NASUI_ListBox;
NASUI_ListBox * NASUI_CreateListBox(int x, int y, int width, int height);

void NASUI_AddListBoxItem(NASUI_ListBox *list, const char *text);

int NASUI_GetListBoxSelectedIndex(NASUI_ListBox *list);
char * NASUI_GetListBoxSelectedItem(NASUI_ListBox *list);
// Don't forget to wash ha... free memory

typedef void (*NASUI_onListBoxSelect)(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_ListBox *list);
void NASUI_SetOnListBoxSelectHandler(NASUI_ListBox *list, NASUI_onListBoxSelect handler);

//////////////////
// ScrollBar    4
typedef struct NASUI_ScrollBar NASUI_ScrollBar;
NASUI_ScrollBar * NASUI_CreateScrollBar(int x, int y, int width, int height, int orientation, int max, int step);

#define NASUI_SCROLLBAR_VERTICAL 0
#define NASUI_SCROLLBAR_HORIZONTAL 1

typedef void (*NASUI_onScrollBarScroll)(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_ScrollBar *bar);
void NASUI_SetOnScrollBarScrollHandler(NASUI_ScrollBar *bar, NASUI_onScrollBarScroll handler);


#endif
```

#### Actual implementations:

**nasui.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <windows.h>

#include "nasui.h"
#include "nasui_ctrls.h"
#include "nasui_incaps.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Hidden callback functions


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wpar, LPARAM lpar)
{
    //  LOWORD(wpar) == control ID

    //printf("MESSAGE %d\n",msg);
    //printf("WLOW:%d\nWHI:%d\nLLOW:%d\nLHI:%d\n", LOWORD(wpar), HIWORD(wpar), LOWORD(lpar), HIWORD(wpar));
    // 309 - key down
    // 273 - key up
    // 308 - list selection
    // HIWORD(wpar)1024 - textbox key down
    // HIWORD(wpar)768 - textbox key up
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            CREATESTRUCT *crts = (CREATESTRUCT*)lpar;
            NASUI_Window *winptr = (NASUI_Window*)crts->lpCreateParams;

            winptr->hwnd = hwnd;
            SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG)winptr); // storing pointer to Window structure

            if(winptr->events.on_create) 
                winptr->events.on_create(winptr);
            break;
        }
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            NASUI_Window *winptr = ((NASUI_Window*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));

            int close = 1;
            if(winptr->events.on_close)
                close = winptr->events.on_close(winptr);

            if(close)
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            NASUI_Window *winptr = ((NASUI_Window*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));

            if(winptr->events.on_destroy)
                winptr->events.on_destroy(winptr);

            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }

        case 273:
        {
            NASUI_Window *winptr = ((NASUI_Window*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));

            //printf("%d  :::  ", HIWORD(wpar));

            if(winptr->controls[LOWORD(wpar)]->type == 1
                    && HIWORD(wpar) == 0)
            {
                NASUI_Button *tctrl = (NASUI_Button*)winptr->controls[LOWORD(wpar)];
                if(tctrl->on_buttonclick)
                    tctrl->on_buttonclick(winptr, tctrl);
            }
            else if(winptr->controls[LOWORD(wpar)]->type == 2
                    && HIWORD(wpar) == 768)
            {
                NASUI_TextBox *tctrl = (NASUI_TextBox*)winptr->controls[LOWORD(wpar)];
                if(tctrl->on_textboxkeypress)
                    tctrl->on_textboxkeypress(winptr, tctrl);
            }
            else if(winptr->controls[LOWORD(wpar)]->type == 3
                    && HIWORD(wpar) == 1)
            {
                NASUI_ListBox *tctrl = (NASUI_ListBox*)winptr->controls[LOWORD(wpar)];
                if(tctrl->on_select)
                    tctrl->on_select(winptr, tctrl);
            }
            break;  
        }
        // 217
        // lptr hi previous
        // wptr hi next
        case WM_VSCROLL:
        {
            NASUI_Window *winptr = ((NASUI_Window*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
            //printf("%x:::%x\n",LOWORD(wpar), SB_THUMBPOSITION);
            if(winptr->controls[LOWORD(wpar)]->type == 4)
            {
                NASUI_ScrollBar *tctrl = (NASUI_ScrollBar*)winptr->controls[LOWORD(wpar)];
                SCROLLINFO snfo; memset(&snfo, 0, sizeof(LPSCROLLINFO));
                snfo.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO); snfo.fMask = SIF_ALL;
                GetScrollInfo(tctrl->hwnd, SB_CTL, &snfo);
                                                            printf("pos: %d\n",snfo.nPos);
                switch(LOWORD(wpar))
                {
                    case SB_LINEDOWN: snfo.nPos -= tctrl->step; break;
                    case SB_LINEUP: snfo.nPos += tctrl->step; break;
                    case 5: snfo.nTrackPos = HIWORD(wpar); break;
                    default:break;
                }                                           printf("pos2: %d\n",snfo.nPos);
                snfo.fMask = SIF_POS;
                SetScrollInfo(tctrl->hwnd, SB_CTL, &snfo, TRUE);
            }
            break;
        }

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wpar, lpar);
    }
    return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Library public functions

NASUI_Window * NASUI_CreateWindow(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR cmdargs, int nCmdShow,
                const char *title, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    NASUI_Window *win = malloc(sizeof(NASUI_Window));
    memset(win, 0, sizeof(NASUI_Window));

    win->win_class.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    win->win_class.style = 0;
    win->win_class.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    win->win_class.cbClsExtra = 0;
    win->win_class.cbWndExtra = 0;
    win->win_class.hInstance = hInst;
    win->win_class.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    win->win_class.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    win->win_class.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    win->win_class.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    win->win_class.lpszClassName = title;
    win->win_class.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    win->hInst = hInst;
    win->nCmdShow = nCmdShow;

    win->title = title;
    win->x = x; win->y = y;
    win->w = width; win->h = height;

    win->lastid = 1;
    win->controls = malloc(sizeof(NASUI_Control*));
    win->controls[0] = NULL;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&win->win_class))
    {
        free(win);
        return NULL;
    }
    return win;
}

void NASUI_SetOnCreateHandler(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_onCreate handler){win->events.on_create = handler;}
void NASUI_SetOnCloseHandler(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_onClose handler){win->events.on_close = handler;}
void NASUI_SetOnDestroyHandler(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_onDestroy handler){win->events.on_destroy = handler;}

void NASUI_Run(NASUI_Window *win)
{
    win->hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
            0,
            win->title,
            win->title,
            WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
            win->x, win->y, 
            win->w, win->h,
            HWND_DESKTOP, 
            NULL, 
            win->hInst, 
            win);

    if(!win->hwnd)
    {
        free(win);
        return;
    }

    ShowWindow(win->hwnd, win->nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(win->hwnd);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

**nasui_ctrls.c**

```
#include "stdio.h"

#include <windows.h>

#include "nasui_ctrls.h"
#include "nasui_incaps.h"

/////////////////////////////////
//
// Button

NASUI_Button * NASUI_CreateButton(int x, int y, int width, int height, const char *text)
{
    NASUI_Button *butn = malloc(sizeof(NASUI_Button));
    butn->type = 1;
    butn->hwnd = 0;

    butn->x = x; butn->y = y;
    butn->w = width; butn->h = height;
    butn->text = text;

    butn->on_buttonclick = NULL;

    return butn;
}

void NASUI_SetOnButtonClickHandler(NASUI_Button *button, NASUI_onButtonClick handler) { button->on_buttonclick = handler; }

/////////////////////////////////
//
// TextBox

NASUI_TextBox * NASUI_CreateTextBox(int x, int y, int width, int height, const char *initial_text)
{
    NASUI_TextBox *box = malloc(sizeof(NASUI_TextBox));
    box->type = 2;
    box->hwnd = 0;

    box->x = x; box->y = y;
    box->w = width; box->h = height;
    box->itext = initial_text;

    box->on_textboxkeypress = NULL;

    return box;         
}

void NASUI_SetOnTextBoxKeyPressHandler(NASUI_TextBox *textbox, NASUI_onTextBoxKeyPress handler) { textbox->on_textboxkeypress = handler; }

/////////////////////////////////
//
// ListBox

NASUI_ListBox * NASUI_CreateListBox(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    NASUI_ListBox *list = malloc(sizeof(NASUI_ListBox));
    list->type = 3;
    list->hwnd = 0;

    list->x = x; list->y = y;
    list->w = width; list->h = height;

    list->on_select = NULL;

    return list;
}
void NASUI_AddListBoxItem(NASUI_ListBox *list, const char *text) 
{ 
    SendMessage(list->hwnd, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)text); 
}
int NASUI_GetListBoxSelectedIndex(NASUI_ListBox *list)
{
    return SendMessage(list->hwnd, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
}
char * NASUI_GetListBoxSelectedItem(NASUI_ListBox *list)
{
    int indx = SendMessage(list->hwnd, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
    int ln = SendMessage(list->hwnd, LB_GETTEXTLEN, (WPARAM) indx, 0);
    char *ret = malloc((ln+1)*sizeof(char));
    SendMessage(list->hwnd, LB_GETTEXT, indx, (WPARAM)ret);

    return ret;
}


void NASUI_SetOnListBoxSelectHandler(NASUI_ListBox *list, NASUI_onListBoxSelect handler) { list->on_select = handler; }

/////////////////////////////////
//
// ScrollBar

NASUI_ScrollBar * NASUI_CreateScrollBar(int x, int y, int width, int height, int orientation, int max, int step)
{
    NASUI_ScrollBar *bar = malloc(sizeof(NASUI_ScrollBar));
    bar->type = 4;
    bar->hwnd = 0;

    bar->x = x; bar->y = y;
    bar->w = width; bar->h = height;

    bar->orient = orientation; bar->max = max; bar->step = step;

    bar->on_scroll = NULL;

    return bar;
}

void NASUI_SetOnScrollBarScrollHandler(NASUI_ScrollBar *bar, NASUI_onScrollBarScroll handler){ bar->on_scroll = handler; }


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Direct interaction with WIN32 API

void NASUI_AddControl(NASUI_Window *win, NASUI_Control *ctrl)
{
    switch(ctrl->type)  // creating HWND right now
    {
        case 1:
        {
            NASUI_Button *tctrl = (NASUI_Button*)ctrl;
            tctrl->hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
                        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                        "BUTTON",
                        tctrl->text,
                        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                        tctrl->x, tctrl->y,
                        tctrl->w, tctrl->h,
                        win->hwnd,
                        (HMENU)win->lastid,
                        GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                        NULL);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            NASUI_TextBox *tctrl = (NASUI_TextBox*)ctrl;
            tctrl->hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
                        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                        "EDIT",
                        tctrl->itext,
                        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                        tctrl->x, tctrl->y,
                        tctrl->w, tctrl->h,
                        win->hwnd,
                        (HMENU)win->lastid,
                        GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                        NULL);
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            NASUI_ListBox *tctrl = (NASUI_ListBox*)ctrl;
            tctrl->hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
                        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                        "LISTBOX",
                        "",
                        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | LBS_NOTIFY,
                        tctrl->x, tctrl->y,
                        tctrl->w, tctrl->h,
                        win->hwnd,
                        (HMENU)win->lastid,
                        GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                        NULL);
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            NASUI_ScrollBar *tctrl = (NASUI_ScrollBar*)ctrl;
            tctrl->hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
                        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                        "SCROLLBAR",
                        "",
                        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | 
                        (tctrl->orient == NASUI_SCROLLBAR_HORIZONTAL ? SBS_HORZ : SBS_VERT),
                        tctrl->x, tctrl->y,
                        tctrl->w, tctrl->h,
                        win->hwnd,
                        (HMENU)win->lastid,
                        GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                        NULL);

            SCROLLINFO snfo; memset(&snfo, 0, sizeof(LPSCROLLINFO));
            snfo.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
            GetScrollInfo(tctrl->hwnd, SB_CTL, &snfo);

                snfo.fMask = SIF_RANGE;
                snfo.nMin = 0;
                snfo.nMax = tctrl->max;

            SetScrollInfo(tctrl->hwnd, SB_CTL, &snfo, TRUE);
            break;
        }
    }
    ctrl->ID = win->lastid;
    ++win->lastid;
    win->controls = realloc(win->controls, sizeof(NASUI_Control*) * win->lastid);
    win->controls[win->lastid-1] = ctrl;
}
```

**nasui_incaps.h**

```
#ifndef NASUI_INCAPS_H
#define NASUI_INCAPS_H

/*
*   CAUTION: this things mean to be incapsulated
*        and they strongly depend on other NASUI components.
*        This file was created only to simplify compilation
*        and increase code re-usage.
*/

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// nasui.c

struct NASUI_WindowEvents // private
{
    NASUI_onCreate on_create;

    NASUI_onClose on_close;
    NASUI_onDestroy on_destroy;
};
struct NASUI_Window // private
{
    // NASUI part
    NASUI_WindowEvents events;

    const char *title;
    int x, y;
    int w, h;

    // WINAPI part
    HINSTANCE hInst;
    int nCmdShow;

    WNDCLASSEX win_class;
    HWND hwnd;

    int lastid;             // last avaible ID, can be assigned to a control
    NASUI_Control **controls;   // table of controls, each entry's ID is it's index in array
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// nasui_ctrls.c

struct NASUI_Control
{
    unsigned char type;
    HWND hwnd;
    int ID;

    int x, y;
    int w, h;
};

struct NASUI_Button
{
    unsigned char type;
    HWND hwnd;
    int ID;

    int x, y;
    int w, h;
    const char *text;

    NASUI_onButtonClick on_buttonclick;
};

struct NASUI_TextBox
{
    unsigned char type;
    HWND hwnd;
    int ID;

    int x, y;
    int w, h;
    const char *itext;

    NASUI_onTextBoxKeyPress on_textboxkeypress;
};

struct NASUI_ListBox
{
    unsigned char type;
    HWND hwnd;
    int ID;

    int x, y;
    int w, h;

    NASUI_onListBoxSelect on_select;
};

struct NASUI_ScrollBar
{
    unsigned char type;
    HWND hwnd;
    int ID;

    int x, y;
    int w, h;

    int orient; int max; int step;

    NASUI_onScrollBarScroll on_scroll;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what problem you're trying to solve here? Why would one use this wrapper instead of just directly using Win32? Also, could you post the definitions of `NASUI_Window`, `NASUI_Button`, `NASUI_TextBox`, etc.

Comment: Win32 API is very complicated and uncomfortable to use, it requires writing tons of code. Even simple window creation can take dozens of lines of code.

Comment: That's official "Hello world" guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx

Comment: Where are the actual *implementations* of your wrapper functions?

Comment: is it enough now?